# Openpyxl: Add dataframe to a range in excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am currently using openpyxl to append by dataframe to a cell in excel. I have the below dataframe.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

print ("Opening Workbook...")
wb = op.load_workbook(r"file_test.xlsx")

seg_IP=df_Seg[df_Seg['B_Name'] == 'ABS']
df_test = pd.DataFrame(seg_IP.groupby('Exit_S')['Exit_S'].count())
Input : df_test
Output :       
    Column_A  Column_B                                    
    ABC           3
    DEF           88
    GHI           91
```

I want to include the dataframe in my worksheet in Cell ($D$15). How do I do that? I wrote the below code but not sure what to do after this. Where should I assign value to range or cell number using openpyxl?

```
for r in dataframe_to_rows(segment_MLE, index=True, header=True):
    sht_1_Segmentation.append(r)
```

Comment: You just need to pad the rows with `None` to start where you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use pandas `DataFrame` method `to_excel`, there's a little bit of setup:

```
xl_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'file_test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
xl_writer.book = wb
xl_writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in wb.worksheets}
df_test.to_excel(xl_writer, 'sheet_name', index=False, startcol=3, startrow=15)
```

I think that there are some utilities for converting column name (eg 'D') to column number (eg 3).

Comment: But how do I save the file with a different file name?

Comment: @Raj I didn't see that in the original question.  The filename used when creating the `xl_writer` will be the file that is saved.  To save the book you just need to add the line `xl_writer.save()`